# How to create a dynamic dropdown in Excel without Visual Basic

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I searched for the below but found little.

I am trying to avoid VBA but I would like to create a dynamic dropdown that filters out value based on a second dataset.

In the below screenshot for example, I would like B not to be proposed as it is flagged as No on the relative cells.

I understood you can create a List from a string but did not understand how to do it dynamically with a formula.

Thank you for your help!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use this as reference:
In cell B6 use this formula

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$1:$G$1; MATCH(0;IF($B$5=$A$2:$G$2; COUNTIF($A$6:A$6; $A$1:$G$1); ""); 0));"")
```

Make sure you enter it with CRTL + SHIFT + ENTER (array fomrula)
After that expand this formula from B6 to C,D,... columns in row 6

[Result image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BTdbh.jpg)

In cell B5 you can enter criteria to get only Y or N values from your vertical list.

Then use values from row 6 in your drop down list.

Comment: Also, if you want to remove empty cells you can use [this](https://www.myonlinetraininghub.com/excel-ignore-blanks-in-data-validation-list) as good source information

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer. The solution looks good but typing the formula I have an error

Comment: what kind of error? Make sure to enter this formula in cell B6, copy and paste, make sure to confirm with **CRTL+SHIFt+ENTER**